# DbContext has been disposed in custom RoleProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ninject

I have a problem with my DbContext being disposed when used in my `CustomRoleProvider`.

I've setup my bindings like to:

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IGenericRepository<>)).To(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

I'm using this NuGet package *Ninject.MVC5 v3.2.1.0* so Ninject is set as the primary DependencyResolver in MVC. Hence why I'm able to do this `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IGenericRepository<User>>()`.

But for some reason the context is disposed.

I tried adding this binding to my setup:

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().WhenInjectedInto<RoleProvider>();
```

But that doesn't work either. I also tried injecting via property injection

```
[Inject]
public IGenericRepository<User> UserRepository { get; set; };
```

But that just results in a lot of others problems I wasn't able to solve (yet).

As far as I can tell from the error message it's here the is problem triggered from.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        User.IsInRole("Admin"); // calls my CustomRoleProvider
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

`CustomRoleProvider` implementation

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private readonly IGenericRepository<User> _userRepository;

    public CustomRoleProvider()
    {
        // using Service Locator (anti pattern)
        // cause MVC do not support DI in role providers (yet)
        _userRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IGenericRepository<User>>();
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Username == username && x.Role.Name == roleName); // dbcontext is here disposed...
        return user.Any();
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Username == username).Select(x => x.Role.Name); // dbcontext is here disposed...
        return user.ToArray();
    }

    // omitted...
}
```

`IGenericRepository<T>` implementation

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> AsQueryable()
    {
        return _dbSet.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Error message

```
[InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CheckContextNotDisposed() +34
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +30
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +20
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +79
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +64
   System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +81
   Presentation.Web.Providers.CustomRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) in ~\Application\Presentation.Web\Providers\CustomRoleProvider.cs:38
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +183
   Presentation.Web.Controllers.BaseController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in ~\Application\Presentation.Web\Controllers\BaseController.cs:27
   ...
```

Comment: You appear to have trimmed out any code that could actually help us determine where the context is being disposed! Can you add that in?

Comment: What parts did you have in mind? To me that's all the code that is run :)

Comment: Well the content of the `IsUserInRole` method for a start.

Comment: Added. But it's pretty straight forward :)

Comment: But we are getting closer... how about the repository `Get` method?

Comment: Changed the logic a bit so it's clearer what is going on with the repo :)

Comment: No offence, but changing the code like that implies that what you are posting doesn't fully match what you are running for real. This code will not throw an error so there must be more to it. Do you have any `using` statements for example? That is a common way to get context disposal exceptions.

Comment: None taken :) I changed the running code to be as the above. It gives the same error. I included the error message if that can somehow help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So apparently the life cycle of RoleProvider is the entire lifespan of the MVC application. (can't remember where I read it)

So have to resolve the dependency in each method :(

```
public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        var userRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IGenericRepository<User>>();
        var user = userRepository .AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Username == username && x.Role.Name == roleName); // dbcontext is here disposed...
        return user.Any();
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        var userRepository = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IGenericRepository<User>>();
        var user = userRepository .AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Username == username).Select(x => x.Role.Name); // dbcontext is here disposed...
        return user.ToArray();
    }

    // omitted...
}
```

Don't understand why this didn't work then

```
kernel.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().WhenInjectedInto<RoleProvider>();
```

I even tried adding `InSingletonScope`

Comment: As for why the last line of code didn't help, your role provider only ever gets created once so it makes no difference.

Comment: But if the DbContext when injected into a RoleProvider is a singleton then it shouldn't be disposed